# Hadoop removes MapReduce history when it is restarted

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

I am carrying out several Hadoop tests using TestDFSIO and TeraSort benchmark tools. I am basically testing with different amount of datanodes in order to assess the linearity of the processing capacity and datanode scalability.

During the above mentioned process, I have obviously had to restart several times all Hadoop environment. Every time I restarted Hadoop, all MapReduce jobs are removed and the job counter starts again from "job_2013*_0001". For comparison reasons, it is very important for me to keep all the MapReduce jobs up that I have previously launched. So, my question is:

¿How can I avoid Hadoop removes all MapReduce-job history after it is restarted?
¿Is there some property to control job removing after Hadoop environment restarting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the MR job history logs are not deleted right way after you restart hadoop, the new job will be counted from *_0001 and only new jobs which are started after hadoop restart will be displayed on resource manager web portal though. In fact, there are 2 log related settings from [yarn default](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml):

```
# this is where you can find the MR job history logs
yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs = ${yarn.log.dir}/userlogs 

# this is how long the history logs will be retained
yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds = 10800
```

and the default ${yarn.log.dir} is defined in $HADOOP_HONE/etc/hadoop/yarn-env.sh.

```
YARN_LOG_DIR="$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/logs"
```

BTW, similar settings could also be found in mapred-env.sh if you are use Hadoop 1.X

Comment: Thank you Zhutoulala for your answer. I though any body would give me an answer. I will test your suggestion!