# How to prevent job log deletion after Hadoop cluster restart?

Tags: hadoop

I check job history and view job logs in Hadoop UI. After cluster restart job history is clear.

Is there any setting to prevent log deletion? Due to my observations, hadoop UI just displays logs that are stored on cluster machines, so I suspect that there's a way to leave logs on cluster restart. Hadoop version is 2.4.0.

Comment: does this suggestion to keep the logs for a longer time help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645557/hadoop-removes-mapreduce-history-when-it-is-restarted Another related post is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713587/how-to-keep-yarns-log-files

Comment: @vefthym first question seems similar, but I don't understand the answer. If counter starts from 1 after cluster restart, there seems no way to access old logs from web UI.